# SQL Exclude via Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to pull member records back from the 'MEMBER' table. I need to retrieve last name, first name, relationship, entrydate, member ID, email and site ID. The criteria are a relationship of 'P', a siteid of '111' and a non-blank email address AND I need to exclude two subsets. Subset A has all of the criteria above plus a User Defined Field with a user defined field id of 26, a user defined field value of 'No' and an entry date of more than 6 days ago. Subset B has the same main criteria but an entry date of more than 2 weeks ago and a User Defined Field of 25 and a used defined field value of 25. The User Defined fields and values are stored in a separate table (MEMBERUDFS) from the Member data. The tricky part is if a user has not set the value of a user defined field there isn't an entry on the MEMBERUDFS table. The two table are linked with the key of memid.

This is what I have so far and it does not exclude group A and I have not attempted to add logic to exclude group B. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! :

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode,
    MEMBERS.memid,
    MEMBERS.fname,
    MEMBERS.lname,
    MEMBERS.relationship,
    MEMBERS.STATUS,
    MEMBERS.email,
    MEMBERS.entrydate,
    SITES.sitename
FROM MEMBERS
INNER JOIN SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS.memid
INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P')
    AND (MEMBERS.email <> '')
    AND (
        MEMBERS.memid NOT IN (
            SELECT MEMBERS_1.memid
            FROM MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1
            INNER JOIN SITES AS SITES_1 ON MEMBERS_1.siteid = SITES_1.siteid
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_1 ON MEMBERS_1.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid
            INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1 ON MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1.udfid
            WHERE (MEMBERS_1.relationship = 'P')
                AND (MEMBERS_1.email <> '')
                AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '26')
                AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'No')
                AND (MEMBERS_1.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, 6, GETDATE()))
                AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite)
            )
        )
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a row of data that you are trying to exclude that is not being excluded by your current query?   It looks ok at first glance.

Comment: memid, lname, fname, relationship, email, entrydate, siteid would be 1234, Doe, John, P, johndoe@gmail.com, 04-15-2016 00:00:00:00, 111 where the UDF of 26 has a value of 'No'

Comment: In your subquery you are using a left join to MEMBERUDFS but then you also have where predicates referencing that table. That pattern effectively turns that left join into an inner join.

Comment: @SeanLange I saw that too, but it shouldn't contribute to the problem OP is describing.

Comment: @Merlin I suspect a data issue.  You shouldn't be able to get the behavior you describe with this query.   Can you set up a SQLFiddle that reproduces the issue?   I think probably your data isn't what you think it is.  Another thing you could do is temporarily add the UDF fields to your select list to see what values are being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should be able to use NOT EXISTS here and remove the UDF tables from your main query, since you're not selecting anything from them.

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode,
    MEMBERS.memid,
    MEMBERS.fname,
    MEMBERS.lname,
    MEMBERS.relationship,
    MEMBERS.STATUS,
    MEMBERS.email,
    MEMBERS.entrydate,
    SITES.sitename
FROM MEMBERS
INNER JOIN SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
WHERE (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P')
    AND (MEMBERS.email <> '')
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT  1 
        FROM    MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_1 ON MEMBERS_1.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid
                INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1 ON MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1.udfid
        WHERE   MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid 
                AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '26')
                AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'No')
                AND (MEMBERS.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, 6, GETDATE()))
    )
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but I also see no reason why this would have different results than the OP's current query.

Comment: @TabAlleman yeah not sure about the memid uniqueness but it would have different result because you take out the JOIN to MEMBERUDFSETUPS since those records might not exist

Comment: True, but that should only result in more records being returned, while OP described the problem as too many records being returned.

Comment: Too many records being returned would also be a result of the unnecessary joins.. this is really not much different that what he claims is working now.. not sure why they need DISTINCT though

Comment: JamieD77 you are correct. After removing all of the additional joins the DISTINCT was not necessary and was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you rephrase the query this way:

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode,
    MEMBERS.memid,
    MEMBERS.fname,
    MEMBERS.lname,
    MEMBERS.relationship,
    MEMBERS.STATUS,
    MEMBERS.email,
    MEMBERS.entrydate,
    SITES.sitename
FROM MEMBERS
INNER JOIN SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERUDFS ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS.memid
INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P')
    AND (MEMBERS.email <> '')
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
    AND NOT (MEMBERS.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, 6, GETDATE()) AND EXISTS
        (SELECT memid FROM MEMBERUDFS WHERE (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '26') 
         AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue = 'No') 
         AND (MEMBERUDFS.memid = MEMBERS.memid)))
```

Comment: No, this is not the same logic.   This would return MemIds where there is a UDF value of 26/No as long as there are other rows related to the same MemId that are not.

Comment: Gentlemen, I have figured out the issue with all of your help. The issue seemed to reside with the fact that once I moved some of the exclusion logic to a subquery, I no longer required all of the JOINS in the main query. Once I removed those lines, I was able to pull the correct data with the exclusion of subquery A. Now I just need to add the logic for subquery B and I will be set. This is the query that worked for subquery A:

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT scancode, memid, fname, lname, relationship, status, email, entrydate
FROM            MEMBERS
WHERE        (relationship = 'P') AND (email <> '') AND (siteid = @rvSite) AND

Comment: (memid NOT IN
                             (SELECT        MEMBERS_1.memid
                               FROM            MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 INNER JOIN
                                                         SITES AS SITES_1 ON MEMBERS_1.siteid = SITES_1.siteid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                         MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_1 ON MEMBERS_1.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                                                         MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1 ON MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1.udfid

Comment: WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.relationship = 'P') AND (MEMBERS_1.email <> '') AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '26') AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'No') AND 
                                                         (MEMBERS_1.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, 6, GETDATE())) AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite)))

Comment: I still suspect a data issue.  I don't see any logical way that your new query would fix the problem you describe in your old query.